# Trying to synch Flex Builder/Eclipse project with SVN source tree

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, svn, flexbuilder, subclipse

I am trying to link a Flex Builder WTP/Eclipse project with an existing SVN source structure.  I'm using subclipse within Eclipse.

Below is a mapping of some of the directories:

Flex Builder/Eclipse Structure -> SVN Directory Structure

-flex_src -> flex/src

-flex_libs -> flex/libs

-java_src -> java/src

-WebContent -> web

** How can I get these directories mapped so that subclipse will recognize that they are svn directories so that I can manage the svn files from within the Flex Builder/Eclipse project???? ****

NOTE:  I'm trying to avoid checking the entire Flex Builder project as I really want just the source in svn.  I know this is debatable but this is what we have right now.

I've tried a number of things such as linking source folders or importing source from my SVN workspace, etc. but subclipse never seems to pick up the fact that these files are in an SVN repository.

Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the necessary things from Team > SVN enabled in your Flex/custom perspective?

AFAIK Subclipse recognizes the presence of SVN based on the existence of the `.svn` meta data within a given directory. My guess would be that its doing this jsut fine and that you dont have the right commands and what not from the typical SVN perspective enabled within your Flex/custom perspective. Youll need to add these i think if you want to use the Subclipse tools.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my experience subclipse isn't the most flexible (haha) SVN tool around, so if it isn't picking on the SVN information correctly it might be easier to check out the three directories as separate projects and link those projects. This is at least if you don't have update them all every day... I'd love to see a real solution to this, though.

Answer (score 0):

prodigitalson and tehmou - thanks for the responses.

I did have subclipse installed correctly but you are right that the team svn options would not show up but I believe this was due to the fact that there was no .svn directory at the top-level of the project.

I worked with another engineer and we didn't have much luck with subclipse in figuring this out. I would agree with tehmou that it does not seem very flexible.

For the time being we simply altered the Flex Builder project to match-up with the SVN directory structure but I still feel like I'm missing some way of being able to match the original directories. But, for now, at least I can manage my source files with SVN within Flex Builder/Eclipse.